# how to pass token and token seceret to oauth swift

Tags: ios, oauth, swift4, oauth-1.0a

How to pass token and token secret on oauth swift lib

i found following code on git documentation of lib

```
// create an instance and retain it
let oauthswift = OAuth1Swift(
    consumerKey:    "********",
    consumerSecret: "********"
)
// do your HTTP request without authorize
oauthswift.client.get("https://api.example.com/foo/bar",
    success: { response in
        //....
    },
    failure: { error in
        //...
    }
)
```

But along with consumerKey and consumerSecret i have token and TokenSecret too. so where i can pass that in oAuthSwift lib.

I tried following code

```
let  oauthswift = OAuth1Swift(
            consumerKey:"102xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            consumerSecret:"5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            token:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            tokenSeceret:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        )
```

but it gives error that "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'OAuth1Swift' with an argument list"
there is Another initializer available in this lib as follow

```
// create an instance and retain it
oauthswift = OAuth1Swift(
    consumerKey:    "********",
    consumerSecret: "********",
    requestTokenUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
    authorizeUrl:    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
    accessTokenUrl:  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
)
// authorize
let handle = oauthswift.authorize(
    withCallbackURL: URL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/twitter")!,
    success: { credential, response, parameters in
      print(credential.oauthToken)
      print(credential.oauthTokenSecret)
      print(parameters["user_id"])
      // Do your request
    },
    failure: { error in
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }             
)
```

but we don't have such links to get token instead we used already created token and secrete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Following Two lines before calling request

```
oauthswift.client.credential.oauth_token = {your stored token}
oauthswift.client.credential.oauth_token_secret = {your stored secret token}
```

i.e Your code become

```
// create an instance and retain it
let oauthswift = OAuth1Swift(
    consumerKey:    "********",
    consumerSecret: "********"
)

//Set Token and TokenSecret
    oauthswift.client.credential.oauth_token = "asxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    oauthswift.client.credential.oauth_token_secret = "1cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


// do your HTTP request
oauthswift.client.get("https://api.example.com/foo/bar",
    success: { response in
        //....
    },
    failure: { error in
        //...
    }
)
```

Comment: Is it possible without oauth token and secret ?

Comment: This code for OAuth implementation, if it oAuth is not your requirement then you can skip it but API is secured by OAuth 1.x then you have to pass this credentials to the client